# 5 boys and 5 girls can be seated in a row

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to seat 5 girls and 5 boys in a row of 10 chairs if

1. Each girl sits next to two boys (except at the ends) and vice versa?

My solution: The girls can be seated in $5!$ ways, and the boys can also be seated in 5! ways.  But since there are two ways to seat the "first" chair, the first one being a boy and the first one being a girl, we multiply by 2 to get $5!\cdot 5!\cdot 2$ total ways

2. At least two girls sit next to each other?

My Solution: We can use string method here and subtract it from total arrangement possible like so: $10! - 6! \cdot 5!$ ($6!$ because $5!$ boys arrangement and all girls are considered as one therefore $6$) and $5!$ because girls can arrange themselves.

But the given solution for the second question is $10! - 5!\cdot5!\cdot 2$; Please help here

Comment: What does "all the girls do not want to sit together" mean?   
Does that mean that no two girls may be next to each other? Something else?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Looking at the official solution, it appears that the solution to $\#2$ is meant to be the complement of the solution to $\#1$, but that is hard to understand from the stated rules.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: If you are trying to calculate the number of arrangements in which the girls do not all sit together, then your answer to the second question makes sense.  The official answer counts the number of arrangements in which not all the boys sit together or not all the girls sit together.